# Making Excel notes

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am looking for a way to create this kind of notes for Excel selected. auto shows when cell is selected

[image]

Comment: http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/playing_sound_from_excel/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to Data -> Data Tools -> Data Validation
2. Click on the second tab ("Input Message")
3. Input your message. The title (if any) will appear in bold
4. Make sure "Show input message when cell is selected" is checked

[image]

5. Click "OK"